# Read JSON file in Java

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON file that contains key - value type information. This information consists of characters that are stored in 8x8 matrix . When I read it returns the entire contents of the file and what i want to do is get the value of each line of the matrix.

```
{"1":"1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1","2":"1 1 O O O O 1 1","3":"1 1 O O O O 1 1","4":"O 1 
  1 O O 1 1 O","5":"O 1 1 1 1 1 1 O","6":"O O 1 1 1 1 O O","7":"O O O O O O
  O O","8":"O O O O O O O O","time":"0.2"}
```

That is the content of the file and showing console me and what I want to show me is just 1 and O.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {

            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("pruebame.json"));

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;


            // loop array
            JSONArray tag = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Tags");
            Iterator iterator = tag.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
```

What i need is to get the following format:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  
1 1 O O O O 1 1  
1 1 O O O O 1 1  
O 1 1 O O 1 1 O  
O O 1 1 1 1 O O  
O O 1 1 1 1 O O
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `jsonObject.getString("idName")`

```
for(int i=1; i<=8; i++){
    System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("" + i));
}
```